# Нужен ли предлог в

Tags: грамотная-речь

Дата и время проведения аукциона: 30.07.2015г. 9.00 по адресу: (далее идет адрес). Нужен ли предлог "в" перед 9.00 и запятая перед "по адресу". Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немножко неудобная конструкция. Тут есть две возможности: либо текст, вот так: "Аукцион состоится 30 июля 2015 года в 9.00 по адресу:..." - либо список, вот так:

- Дата проведения аукциона: 30.07.2015;
- время: 9.00;
- адрес:...

В случае текста запятая не нужна, в случае списка строки отделяются точкой с запятой. Предложенный вами вариант оттого и неясен, что представляет собой гибрид, восприятие затрудняет и цифровая строка, которую так и хочется разбить надвое предлогом "в", да списочный формат начала фразы ("дата и время...) не позволяет...